# Need to include Tabs with Nav Drawer

Tags: android

My main activity layout uptil now looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" >
            </include>

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="android.mybitchinapp.com.testgui.activity.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" >
    </fragment>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I need to include a TabLayout in order to provide tabs to the app. I cant figure out how to include it. I tried to add an AppBarLayout (which would contain TabLayout) but it leads to app crash. So its obviously not a solution. How do I edit it to make it have a TabLayout too?
Final product required is : 
[image]

Mine looks like this: 
[image]

That is, it has fragments and tha nav drawer. The only missing this is the actual tabs.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

Comment: I understand already that I need a TabLayout. I just want to know where I should put it in my layout. Putting it in DrawerLayout directly is causing app to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **xml** layout seems confusing. So I have edited your xml as a basic idea  to achieve what you need as your given screenshot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <include
                   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                   layout="@layout/toolbar" >
                </include>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

         </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

            <fragment 
                android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"          
                android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" >
            </fragment>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Reference: http://hmkcode.com/material-design-app-android-design-support-library-appcompat/

Comment: Thanks for the source too.

Answer (score 1):

see this solution https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

[Source Code](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/archive/master.zip)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your current layout, you could just add the `TabLayout` after the toolbar include.

```
<!-- snip -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="some_size" />

</LinearLayout>
<!-- snip -->
```

Comment: That is leading to the app crashing on installation :/

Comment: @leehuang it would have been helpful for you to include what you did _in code_ and a stack trace in your post. We aren't psychic :/